# What is the proper way to limit access to many pages upon user basis?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

Restrict access. I have a table that, to simplify has 3 columns. user, pass, access.

I have 4 types of pages... One requires 1, aka super admin. Another requires 2, aka general admin... the other 3, for mod. The last, any USER may access.

I can write the code, but how should I do it?

I came up with 2 options on my own: **Function that goes into my library** or **include file that I include and if they shouldn't be able to access, it redirects to "restricted"**.

Are there other options? What's the most common way to do this? The most efficient to re-use code.

Comment: Are you using a framework?  Zend has authentication and authorization modules.

Comment: Just smarty template manager if it means anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only real piece of advice: don't write your own ACL library.. there are plenty of them out there. Take a look at https://packagist.org/search/?q=acl and see if there's one that looks like it would fit your use case. I've been looking at https://github.com/alexshelkov/SimpleAcl and it may be a good one to start with (I haven't used it myself though).

Comment: Could you explain acl's further? I don't care if it's link reading I just want proper info.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with this: http://www.developer.com/lang/php/creating-a-custom-acl-in-php.html answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about what you're trying to achieve. The way I usually go, is to hide links based on access level. If a use isn't permitted to view specific content, create a function to hide the link and only show it to users with the right permissions.

If a user types the URL of a restricted page, then they should be redirected to a default page, maybe the home page, or a page that explains why they can't go "here". You only need to test the privilege, and have one default target page. Any "secure" page should simply test the current access level against the page's level, and redirect if not equal or greater.

The alternate way is to create a default "access denied" page that loads when sufficient privileges aren't available to the user.

I always go with the first method. It's simple enough to implement, and reduces many headaches, and, most importantly, user frustration. It's more of a user interface question than a programming question.

Ask yourself this, how annoying would amazon.com be if there were admin links on the site that didn't go anywhere?

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking. I know to hide links, but if they type into the url bar an admin only page, I need to redirect to restricted. I need to know if I should make 4 include files "superadmin.php", "admin.php", "mod.php", "user.php" or 4 subfunctions or anything else

Comment: Well, I edited my answer with some more detail. Security is always better when it provides little or no information as to what is needed, i.e. don't tell the user what they need to see the content, just tel them they can't see it. One page, one redirect. You could perhaps redirect to a login page, but that only makes sense if they're not logged in at all. And even then, you only need one login page. I don't know why you would need several includes. Provide as few details as possible. They only need to know they can't go to the content.

Comment: You still aren't understanding completely, but I guess I could have one include "checklogin.php"
and before I include it, make a variable `$accessrequired = 2`?
Is that an option?

Comment: Sure, you basically need a function that understands what is needed, and tests it against what is offered. I do this in my framework. I check the current user against the necessary level, and either proceed or bail based on that. In an OOP context, you would have a security class available, and call a method that takes two arguments, current, required, and takes action or does nothing (allow the page to load).